# Goolge Cloud Spanner DML insert timestamp

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

As mentioned in the [Spanner Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-dml-standard-update-with-timestamp)
we can use PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP() for the `update query`

as shown below

```
const [rowCount] = await transaction.runUpdate({
      sql: `UPDATE Albums
        SET LastUpdateTime = PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP()
        WHERE SingerId = 1`,
    });
```

What if we want to use for `insert query` with [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/timestamp_functions)

If we use in the transaction getting the following error

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Could not cast literal "COMMIT_TIMESTAMP()" to type TIMESTAMP
```

is there is other way we can insert the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP using query?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a typo in your code (or otherwise in your question):

1. You can use `PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP()` to set the value of a column to the commit timestamp of the transaction.
2. You can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` to get the current timestamp.

Your error message however shows `COMMIT_TIMESTAMP()`. That is not a valid Cloud Spanner function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() set the current time when updating a record.
`UPDATE Albums SET LastUpdateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE SingerId = 1`